# Why do we need to return Point object in __add__ function instead of just returning x and y?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I'm studying operator overloading in Python and came accross with this chunk of code. It is not clear to me, why do we return Point(x,y) in **add** function instead of just returning x  and y.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0 , y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    
    def __str__(self):
        return("({0},{1})" .format(self.x, self.y))    
    
    
    def __add__(self , other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y + other.y
        return Point(x, y) // here if we remove Point object and use return(x,y) it does not cause any errors
        
        
p1 = Point(1,5)  
p2 = Point(2,5)

print(p1 + p2)
```

Comment: The reason would be more obvious if you didn't have that `__str__` method that makes your `Point` instances look mostly like tuples.

Comment: Because you want to get back a `Point` instance and not a tuple.

Comment: You want `+` to be *closed*, in the algebraic sense. Otherwise, in order to implement `p1 + p2 + p3`, you'll have to make `__add__` be able to add a `Point` and a `tuple` together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (x,y) syntax creates a tuple object, while Point(x,y) creates an instance of the Point class and sets it's x and y properties.

There is a difference between these two types of python objects. A tuple is a sequence type object, which is formal talk for a list of values.  A tuple, by itself, only has the two values, and the methods that apply for that type of collection. You can read more about tuples here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple

On the other hand, while your Point class is still quite simple, can have much additional functionality via other methods. For example, the tuple will probably not have the **add**() method you are creating in your point class, or it may have another **add**() method which does something else. Hope this clears this up.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I study the details too much and occasionally even some basic things can confuse me. @tutiplain